# C# Finding largest connected area of adjacent empty cells (string[,])

Tags: c#, string, matrix, area

I'm trying to find the largest connected area of adjacent empty cells (diagonal connection counts).

For example if I have a matrix like this (" "-Empty, "F"-Filled)

```
{" "," "," ","F"},
{"F","F","F"," "},
{" "," ","F"," "}
```

The result should be:

```
{"*","*","*","F"},
{"F","F","F","*"},
{" "," ","F","*"}
```

Any other ideas except the good old BFS/DFS?

Here is my working code (solved with BFS):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _09.LargestConnectedArea
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string[,] matrix;
        public static int mRow, mCol;

        public static void Input(string mode = "mid")
        {
            if (mode.Equals("top"))
            {
                matrix = new string[4, 4]{
                {" "," "," "," "},
                {" "," "," "," "},
                {"F"," "," ","F"},
                {" ","F","F"," "}
                };
                mRow = matrix.GetLength(1);
                mCol = matrix.GetLength(0);
            }
            else if (mode.Equals("mid"))
            {
                matrix = new string[4, 4]{
                {"F","F","F"," "},
                {" "," "," "," "},
                {"F"," "," ","F"},
                {"F","F","F","F"}
                };
                mRow = matrix.GetLength(1);
                mCol = matrix.GetLength(0);
            }
            else if (mode == "test")
            {
                // matrix = new string[4, 4];
                matrix = new string[7, 4]{
                {" ","F","F"," "},
                {"F","F"," "," "},
                {" "," "," ","F"},
                {"F","F"," "," "},
                {" ","F"," ","F"},
                {" ","F"," ","F"},
                {" ","F"," ","F"}
                };
                mRow = 7;
                mCol = 4;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("maxrow: ");
                mRow = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("maxcol: ");
                mCol = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                matrix = new string[mRow, mCol];
                for (int row = 0; row < mRow; row++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Row {0}:", row);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    for (int col = 0; col < mCol; col++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Element {0}:", col);
                        matrix[row, col] = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static int BFS(Stack<Tuple<int, int>> currPath, string symbol = "*", int counter = 0)
        {
            if (currPath.Count == 0)
            {
                return counter;
            }
            else
            {
                ;
                Tuple<int, int> top = new Tuple<int, int>(currPath.Peek().Item1, currPath.Pop().Item2);
                matrix[top.Item1, top.Item2] = symbol;
                counter++;
                //top TEST: PASSED
                #region
                if (top.Item1 > 0)
                {
                    //_X_
                    if (matrix[top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2].Equals(" "))
                    {
                        matrix[top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2] = symbol;
                        currPath.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2));
                    }
                    //X__
                    if (top.Item2 > 0)
                    {
                        if (matrix[top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2 - 1].Equals(" "))
                        {
                            matrix[top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2 - 1] = symbol;
                            currPath.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2 - 1));
                        }
                    }
                    //__X
                    if (top.Item2 < mCol - 1)
                    {
                        if (matrix[top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2 + 1].Equals(" "))
                        {
                            matrix[top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2 + 1] = symbol;
                            currPath.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(top.Item1 - 1, top.Item2 + 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
                //mid TEST: PASSED
                #region
                if (top.Item2 > 0)
                {
                    if (matrix[top.Item1, top.Item2 - 1].Equals(" "))
                    {
                        matrix[top.Item1, top.Item2 - 1] = symbol;
                        currPath.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(top.Item1, top.Item2 - 1));
                    }
                }
                if (top.Item2 < mCol - 1)
                {
                    if (matrix[top.Item1, top.Item2 + 1].Equals(" "))
                    {
                        matrix[top.Item1, top.Item2 + 1] = symbol;
                        currPath.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(top.Item1, top.Item2 + 1));
                    }
                }
                #endregion
                //bot TEST: PASSED
                #region
                if (top.Item1 < mRow - 1)
                {
                    //_X_
                    if (matrix[top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2].Equals(" "))
                    {
                        matrix[top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2] = symbol;
                        currPath.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2));
                    }
                    //X__
                    if (top.Item2 > 0)
                    {
                        if (matrix[top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2 - 1].Equals(" "))
                        {
                            matrix[top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2 - 1] = symbol;
                            currPath.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2 - 1));
                        }
                    }
                    //__X
                    if (top.Item2 < mCol - 1)
                    {
                        if (matrix[top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2 + 1].Equals(" "))
                        {
                            matrix[top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2 + 1] = symbol;
                            currPath.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(top.Item1 + 1, top.Item2 + 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                return BFS(currPath, symbol, counter);
            }
        }

        public static void Print(string[,] a)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < mRow; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < mCol; col++)
                {
                    Console.Write("\'{0}\' ", a[row, col]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Input("test");
            Print(matrix);

            List<Tuple<char, int>> areaCalculated = new List<Tuple<char, int>>();

            char symbol = '1';

            //Console.WriteLine(BFS(a, symbol + ""));

            for (int row = 0; row < mRow; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < mCol; col++)
                {
                    if (matrix[row, col].Equals(" ") == true)
                    {
                        Stack<Tuple<int, int>> a = new Stack<Tuple<int, int>>();
                        a.Push(new Tuple<int, int>(row, col));

                        areaCalculated.Add(new Tuple<char, int>(symbol, BFS(a, symbol + "")));
                        symbol++;
                    }
                }
            }

            areaCalculated.Sort((x, y) => y.Item2.CompareTo(x.Item2));

            Print(matrix);

            Console.WriteLine("The largest connected area of adjacent empty cells(diagonal connection counts) is marked with the \'"+areaCalculated.ElementAt(0).Item1 + "\' symbol and contains " + areaCalculated.ElementAt(0).Item2 + " cells.");
            // Console.WriteLine(areaCalculated.ElementAt(areaCalculated.Count - 1).Item1 + " " + areaCalculated.ElementAt(areaCalculated.Count - 1).Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define adjacent. Do you mean adjacent cells only in the same row, or does it include columns? Your result suggests that adjacent includes diagonal because you have the last column of the last two rows with a `*`

Comment: And either post your code, or at least a few lines of description as to how your attempt tackled it. If your solution works, then this seems like a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By adjacent I mean cells with at least one common edge/side.
And sorry about posting this here (I'm new to stackoverflow). Maybe you are right, maybe it's for codereview. The reason I posted it here is just to collect some fresh ideas and maybe to find a better solution than mine.

P.S. I'll edit question and post the code. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For marking an entire connected area, I suggest taking a look at the Flood Fill algorithms and their analysis, in order to optimize (by constants, not order of magnitude) the running time - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill. Other than that, it gets very specific according to the type of actual inputs you are getting

Comment: Again sorry for posting this question here #newHere. (@Matt Burland) 

Aand thank you @LightningIsMyName for the suggestion, I'll check it out ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the exercise, this is my attempt

```
var wspace = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
string[,] cells = { 
    { "F", " ", "F", "F", "F", "F", " " }, 
    { "F", "F", "F", " ", "F", "F", " " }, 
    { "F", " ", "F", " ", "F", " ", "F" },
    { "F", "F", " ", "F", "F", " ", "F" },
    { "F", " ", "F", " ", "F", " ", "F" }
};

for (int i = 0; i < cells.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cells.GetLength(1); j++)
        if (cells[i, j] == " ")
            wspace.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));

var region = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
var pre = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
var regions = new List<List<Tuple<int, int>>>();
region.Add(wspace.First());
wspace = wspace.Skip(1).ToList();

for(int z=0; z<wspace.Count(); z++)
{
    var pos = wspace[z];
    bool keep = true;
    for (int i = -1; i < 2 && keep; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2 && keep; j++)
        {
            if (region.Any(x => x.Item1 == (pos.Item1 + i) && x.Item2 == (pos.Item2 + j)))
            {
                pre.Reverse();
                wspace.AddRange(pre);
                pre.Clear();
                region.Add(pos);
                keep = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (keep && (pos.Item1 > region.Last().Item1) && (pos.Item2 > region.Last().Item2))
    {
        regions.Add(region.ToList());
        region.Clear();
        region.Add(pos);
    }
    else if (keep) pre.Add(pos);

}
regions.Add(region);
region = regions.OrderBy(x => x.Count).Last().OrderBy(s => s.Item1 * cells.GetLength(1) + s.Item2).ToList();

region.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Array: {0} Key: {1}", x.Item1 + 1, x.Item2 + 1));
```

So far it worked well, try and tell me

Actual Output

```
Array: 2 Key: 4
Array: 3 Key: 2
Array: 3 Key: 4
Array: 4 Key: 3
Array: 5 Key: 2
Array: 5 Key: 4
```

Comment: I will ^^ I'll let you know tomorrow because I'm exhausted to test it today... I'll also post my solution at the top, feel free to look at it as well and tell me if I can optimize something ^^

Comment: Trying to understand your output. The largest connected area for your example has three solutions of 10 cells. One of them is the series: `[2,0][2,1][3,1][3,2][2,3][3,4][3,5][2,5][1,6][0,6]`

Comment: @Rufus could you try with the actual code? i think i fixed all